# How can I mock/stub out a Flutter platform channel/plugin?

Tags: android, ios, unit-testing, dart, flutter

I read the [introduction to platform-specific plugins/channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) on the Flutter website and I browsed some simple examples of a plugin, like [`url_launcher`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/url-launcher/lib/url_launcher.dart):

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

const _channel = const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher');

/// Parses the specified URL string and delegates handling of it to the
/// underlying platform.
///
/// The returned future completes with a [PlatformException] on invalid URLs and
/// schemes which cannot be handled, that is when [canLaunch] would complete
/// with false.
Future<Null> launch(String urlString) {
  return _channel.invokeMethod(
    'launch',
    urlString,
  );
}
```

In widgets tests or integration tests, how can I mock out or stub channels so I don't have to rely on the real device (running Android or iOS) say, actually launching a URL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use setMockMethodCallHandler to register a mock handler for the underlying method channel:

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMockMethodCallHandler.html

```
final List<MethodCall> log = <MethodCall>[];

MethodChannel channel = const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher');

// Register the mock handler.
TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
          .setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, (message) {
  log.add(methodCall);
});

await launch("http://example.com/");

expect(log, equals(<MethodCall>[new MethodCall('launch', "http://example.com/")]));

// Unregister the mock handler.
channel.setMockMethodCallHandler(null);
```

Comment: Just so readers understand, because `MethodChannel` is a canonical (`const`) object, I can create and `setMockMethodCallHandler` in my own package even if the plugin author did not make `channel` public, right?

Comment: The plugin needs to provide an @visibleForTesting constructor that takes a MethodChannel argument as an alternative to using the default one. The url_launcher doesn't do this yet, but the firebase_analytics plugin is an example of this patterns. Eventually I'm hoping that most plugins will follow this pattern and will be more testable. https://github.com/flutter/firebase_analytics/blob/master/lib/firebase_analytics.dart

Comment: @CollinJackson, Do you have an update on that link? Or a guide? The old link is dead.

Comment: Here's the fixed link https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/lib/firebase_analytics.dart

Here's another more recently updated plugin that is a bit cleaner:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_functions/lib/src/cloud_functions.dart

Comment: @CollinJackson all of those links are dead, can you provide a permanent gist which will never go down instead?

Comment: How to mock PlatformException in methodchannel? I want to test the return value in my catch block.

Comment: MethodChannel.setMockMethodCallHandler has been replaced by TestDefaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler as per https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels

Answer (score 21):

`MethodChannel#setMockMethodCallHandler` is deprecated and removed as of now.

Looks like this is the way to go now:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void mockUrlLauncher() {
  const channel = MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher');

  handler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'yourMethod') {
      return 42;
    }
    return null;
  }

  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, handler);
}
```

The details are on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d7bee5ec948f9707a2052ef714f76197c244baba/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/deprecated.dart#L90-L92).

And here is a tested example for `package_info` plugin for future references:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void mockPackageInfo() {
  const channel = MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/package_info');

  handler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    if (methodCall.method == 'getAll') {
      return <String, dynamic>{
        'appName': 'myapp',
        'packageName': 'com.mycompany.myapp',
        'version': '0.0.1',
        'buildNumber': '1'
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, handler);
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer since Flutter 2.5, more info https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/mock-platform-channels

Comment: `TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance` in my test is nullable so i should add null check ('?' or '!')

Comment: How to mock PlatformException in methodchannel? I want to test the return value in my catch block.

Comment: I cannot find how the "magic incantation" `plugins.flutter.io` was derived: `const channel = MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/package_info');`

Answer (score 8):

When you create a plugin, you are automatically provided a default test:

```
void main() {
  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('my_plugin');

  setUp(() {
    channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      return '42';
    });
  });

  tearDown(() {
    channel.setMockMethodCallHandler(null);
  });

  test('getPlatformVersion', () async {
    expect(await MyPlugin.platformVersion, '42');
  });
}
```

Let me add some notes about it:

- Calling `setMockMethodCallHandler` allows you to bypass whatever the actual plugin does and return your own value.
- You can differentiate methods using `methodCall.method`, which is a string of the called method name.
- For plugin creators this is a way to verify the public API names, but it does not test the functionality of the API. You need to use integration tests for that.

Comment: How to mock PlatformException in methodchannel? I want to test the return value in my catch block.

Comment: @sagarsuri, sorry, I'm not sure right now. Can you do it the same way you expect other types of exceptions?

Comment: I tried it but the exception is not getting mocked and I am not able to test it.

Comment: @sagarsuri, if you post you code as a new answer and link back to it from here I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my channel was private so I couldn't access it. So in general I had something like that:

```
 testWidgets('My test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    //https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76790 - add delay work around
    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      //arrange
      MethodChannel channel = const MethodChannel('my_channel');
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        tester.binding.defaultBinaryMessenger.setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, (message) => null);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    });
  });
```