# What is the right way to unit test Flutter platform channel?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to test Flutter platform Channel, but failed to pass the test cases because of Missing Plugin Exception. How can you unit test Flutter platform channel by `flutter test`?

Comment: You can simply mock the platform channel for now.

Comment: Any instructions？

Comment: nah, but I found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897734/how-can-i-mock-stub-out-a-flutter-platform-channel-plugin . You can give it a try and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look of [this](https://github.com/ZaraclaJ/audio_recorder/blob/master/test/audio_recorder_test.dart) unit test example